# Can I use the DocuSign API to pull recipient status in bulk (multiple envelopes at a time)

Tags: docusignapi

We're having inconsistencies with our DocuSign webhook, so I've been tasked with creating a scheduled call to pull in the recipient status for all open envelopes in our system (generally 30-60 at any given time) I have been unable to find any DocuSign API endpoints which would allow me to pull them in bulk. (I was hoping to find something similar to https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatus where I can pass a list of envelopeIds and get back an array of recipient statuses. To avoid heavily impacting the Hourly limit of 1000 API calls per hour.

Am I on a fool's errand, or is there something I'm missing in the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with that call, but the ListStatusChanges call can: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges

Making a call to `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{{accountid}}/envelopes?envelope_ids=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000,11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111&include=recipients` will include the recipient statuses for envelopes 0000- and 1111-

Note that there is a max URL length. I believe you can query for around 40-50 envelopes in a single call before that max length is exceeded.

Comment: oh, this looks like what I was looking for, thanks for your help Drew!

Comment: This appears to be mostly correct. I called ListStatus instead of ListStatusChanges. I comma delimited the envelopeIDs and it appears to work. It returned a list of type EnvelopesInformation